# Is this the correct way to use localStorage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

I want to be able to switch themes using a  element. The themes are stored in different .css files and by picking a different `<option>`, I can in turn pick a different theme. However, switching pages switches themes back to whatever I have currently written into my actual template. Here is my .js file:

```
$(function() {
    var theme = $("#theme");
    var getTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
    
    
    $("#select option:selected").each(function() { /* Switch on-change function */
        if (getTheme == $(this).data("theme")) {
            theme.attr("href", getTheme); /* Set the theme of the page to whatever theme applies to this option */
            console.log($(this).data("theme"));
        }
        else {
            theme.attr("href", $(this).data("theme"));
            localStorage.setItem("theme", $(this).data("theme")); /* Store the choice into local storage; should persist upon page reload */
            console.log($(this).data("theme"));
        }
    });
});
```

And here is my template:

```
<div style="text-align: center">
  <select class="form-control" name="select" id="select">
      <option selected value="original" data-theme="/static/styles.css">Original</option>
      <option value="darkmode" data-theme="/static/stylesdark.css">Dark Mode</option>
      <option value="cybermode" data-theme="/static/stylescyber.css">Cyber Mode</option>
      <option value="fire" data-theme="/static/stylesfire.css">Fire & Brimstone</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I figure my error has something to do with how my use of localStorage is being handled, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: I don't see you set `theme` in `$data()`

Comment: @Rojo Do you mean `var theme = $("#theme");`?

Comment: @Barmar No, I mean `$(this).data("theme")`

Comment: That comes from `data-theme="..."` in the HTML.

Comment: I think you want `if (getTheme == $(this).val())`

Comment: How are any options selected on deocument ready? Where is the onchange that sets this?

Comment: Why do you need `.each()`? There can only be one selected option.

Answer (score 0):

You code seems [for me] very complicated

just do

```html
<div style="text-align: center">
  <select class="form-control" name="select" id="select">
    <option value="/static/styles.css"     > Original      </option>
    <option value="/static/stylesdark.css" > Dark Mode      </option>
    <option value="/static/stylescyber.css"> Cyber Mode      </option>
    <option value="/static/stylesfire.css" > Fire & Brimstone </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

```js
const theSelect = document.querySelector('#select')

theSelect.value = localStorage.getItem('theme') || theSelect.options[0].value 

theSelect.onchange = e =>
  {
  localStorage.setItem('theme', theSelect.value)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a lot more complicated than it needs to be

```
$(function() {

  var theme = $("#theme");
  var select = $("#select");

  function setStyleSheet(selectOption) {
    // use local storage, if no value, use default
    var themeHref = localStorage.getItem("theme") || "/your/default.css";
    // update the stylesheet
    theme.attr("href", themeHref);
    // if we need to, update the option with the value from local storage
    if (selectOption) {
      select.find('option[data-value="' + themeHref + '"]').prop('selected', true);
    }
  }

  // bind change event to the select
  select.on('change', function() {
    // grab selected option
    var theme = select.find("option:selected").data("theme");
    // update local storage
    localStorage.setItem("theme", theme);
    // update the style sheeet
    setStyleSheet(false);
  });

  // update the stylesheet on page load
  setStyleSheet(true);

});
```

If you used the value instead of data attributes this would be even simpler.

```js
$(function() {

  var theme = $("#theme");
  var select = $("#select");

  function setStyleSheet(selectOption) {
    // use local storage, if no value, use default
    var themeHref = localStorage.getItem("theme") || "/your/default.css";
    // update the stylesheet
    theme.attr("href", themeHref);
    // if we need to, update the option with the value from local storage
    if (selectOption) {
      select[0].value = themeHref;
    }
  }

  // bind change event to the select
  select.on('change', function() {
    // grab selected option's value
    var theme = this.value;
    // update local storage
    localStorage.setItem("theme", theme);
    // update the style sheeet
    setStyleSheet(false);
  });

  // update the stylesheet on page load
  setStyleSheet(true);

});
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to make it so that page transition doesn't seem so "clunky"? As I change pages, the original theme can be seen briefly, then the chosen theme becomes selected.

Comment: Also, is there an alternative to "select[0].value = themeHref"? I'm getting a "jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined"

Comment: So why is the select element not on the page? That is the reason for that error

Comment: How can you make it less.... you could document.write out the stylesheet

Comment: Not sure I understand your question fully? Why is the select element not on the page? It is. It could be where I reference the .js code. I placed it in a layout template that every other page references for its general styling.

Comment: If it is there on document.ready, it is unclear why it would not find the select element. That is what the error is stating.